# Can CloudVision count up original character logos from a picture?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, google-cloud-vision

Below image is the game result.
I need to count up some logo in a picture.

What is the best way to count up character logo in the picture?
I'm just web engineer, so I don't want to use tensorflow.
Is it possible to use cloudVision Api to count up character in the picture?

[image: game result]

Above image has 63 character logos in a picture.
I just want to count up character.

What is the best way?
Do I need tensorflow or opencv?

thanks

Comment: if it is a logo, why not template matching? something like the last part of [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) just that counts instead of only showing them

Comment: opencv is little difficult for me... Thanks!

Comment: Since you tagged OpenCV, here are two approaches. 1) Use template matching but the downside is that you need a template for each logo. 2) Contour detection and filtering using aspect ratio and contour area. The idea is that a logo is a square so we can filter using this in addition to a certain contour area

Comment: template matching is suit my case, because my game result image's resolution is very low. I'll try second solution. thanks!